# One query for all data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a React application which does several queries to the backend via Apollo & Graphql. Here is my question:

From a resource / user friendly perspective, is it better to have one component with an all-including query on the main component, and then disburse the subfields to sub-level components for display?

Or is it better to save the resources upfront, and query the subfields when the user actually requires the resources, aka visits the sub-components responsible for displaying?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of your data. If it will be a big chunk of data (multiple MBs) better try to split it into parts and load only needed. But don't split into a smaller ones, because each separate request will take time, and they might slow down load time.